# Thermal expectation from Gauss-Integral partition function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, partition-function

Why is it that, given a partition function $Z$ which takes the form of a Gaussian integral, such equalities hold for the corresponding thermal expectation values, in the example below for the observable $e^{i(\phi(0)-\phi(\vec{r}))}$

$\left\langle e^{i(\phi(0)-\phi(\vec{r})} \right\rangle= e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left\langle (\phi(0)-\phi(\vec{r}))^{2} \right\rangle}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying a bit the notation, you want to know why
$$
\left\langle e^{A}\right\rangle \overset{?}{=}  e^{\frac12 \langle A^2\rangle}\,.
$$
This is a consequence of [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem). In order to see this explicitly write the exponential as the infinite series that defines it
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle e^{A}\right\rangle &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\langle A^n\rangle
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}\langle A^{2k}\rangle\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
The last step follows from the fact that odd point functions vanish in a Gaussian theory. Then we can compute the $2k$-point function as a product of two-point functions as Wick's theorem prescribes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle e^{A}\right\rangle &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{\mathrm{pairings}}\langle A^2\rangle^{k}
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!}\langle A^2\rangle^{k}\,.
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k k!}\langle A^2\rangle^{k}
\\&=e^{\frac12 \langle A^2 \rangle}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

Let's break it down. In the first step I applied Wick's theorem and used the fact that all $A$'s are the same. So all contractions are identical and I need to multiply them $k$ times and then sum over all possible pairings that I can make. Clearly all pairings give identical contributions. A pairing is e.g. $$1234 \to (12)(34)+(13)(24)+(14)(23)\,.$$

Then in the second step I used the fact that the number of pairings is $(2k-1)(2k-3)\cdots = (2k-1)!!$. This is a simple combinatorial exercise. Finally I do some simplifications and get the final answer.